# Show function not working with Materialize and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I have two selects, the second one is hidden and it should be shown if the first select has been changed, I checked it through `on('change', function(){ ...` and it is working so far. I've checked and also showed a `console.log` when the first select box is changed.

The problem here is when I change the value of the first select box, the console.log is showing with value but the **second select box is not showing.**

I have updated *MaterializeCSS* and *jQuery*, this is my script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').material_select();
        $('#school-list').on('change', function() {
            $('#section-list').show();
            console.log(this.value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my selects:

```
            <div class="row margin">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <select id="school-list" name="school-list">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your school</option>
                   ...
                </select>
                <label>School</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row margin" style="display: none">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <select id="section-list" name="section-list">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your section</option>
                   ...
                </select>
                <label>Section</label>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show parent row of second select.

You can try this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').material_select();
        $('#school-list').on('change', function() {
            $('#section-list').parents(".row:eq(0)").show();
            console.log(this.value);
        });
    });
</script>
```